# Requests doesn't work when sending message to discord

Tags: python, post, python-requests, discord

I am trying to send a message with python to discord using requests.. Why doesn't this work? Did I do something wrong?

```
import requests
id = 935325134879850517
r = requests.post(f'http://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{id}/messages', json={'content':'message'}, headers={'authorization': 'token'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Discord webhooks, I had problem with API too, but webhooks works very simple -- without auth.